# socket io server is not responding

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Sometimes request to https:/domain:8050'/socket.io/socket.io.js is returning status "(failed)" in chrome developer tools' network tab.

In Firefox is giving "Secure Connection Failed" error and Aborted status.

Socket IO version is "1.3.5". Node.js version is "v0.10.25".

**server.js**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'),
    options = {
        secureProtocol: 'SSLv23_method',
        secureOptions: require('constants').SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3,
        ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/CA_Bundle.crt'),
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/private.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/public.crt'),
        passphrase: 'pssword'
    },
    app = express();
    server = require('https').Server(options, app);
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    server.listen(8050);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send("server..");
    });
    io.set('transports', ['websocket', 
      'flashsocket', 
      'htmlfile', 
      'xhr-polling', 
      'jsonp-polling', 
      'polling']);

    io.use(function(socket, next)  {
        var handshakeData = socket.request,
            cookie =parseCookies(handshakeData);
        if(!socket.handshake.query || !handshakeData.headers || !handshakeData.headers.cookie)  {
            next(new Error('-Error code:1')); //cookie transmitted
            console.log('cookie transmitted');
            return false;
        }
        else  next();
    });
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("\ncalled connection 8050.");
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain:8050/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('https://domain:8050',{                 
                    'sync disconnect on unload' : false,
                    'connect timeout': 10000,
                    'reconnect': false,
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell express that the socket.io folder is a folder of static content. If you have your socket.io stuff in the node_modules folder you could use `app.use(express.static('node_modules'));`.